# How to use and activate bluetooth for phonegap?

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, bluetooth

I have finished the source code for chess game. Now it's the part the 1 person vs 1 person via bluetooth. how to use, active and manipulate action with bluetooth?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth plugins:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Bluetooth
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BluetoothPlugin