# How to print bluetooth printer /woosim porti w40/ with DXTREME?

Tags: printing, bluetooth, devexpress, devextreme

I have developed mobile application with Devexpress DXTreme, i need to print that data using bluetooth by a bluetooth printer.

help me, how to print!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to access bluetooth devices with DXTREME out of the box. Instead you can use PhoneGap. Here are some related links from the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) which is the best place to ask.

- [How to use bluetooth device (printer) with DXTREME?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q434945)
- [How to access device hardware](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q434945)
- [A StackOverflow answer with some links to PhoneGap bluetooth plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10610123/1077279)